# Run project on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Am trying to run a calculator project on google colab but i don't know how to set up my file structure i think. i have two files,

1. calculator.py
2. test_calculator.py

i have an import statement on test_calculator that imports the calculator .py into it to run the test, but google colab does not see the calculator .py on my notebook i don't know if my structure is wrong

[calculator.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8V9F.png)

[error on the test_calculator.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etggR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need import if they are in the same Notebook but different cells. Just call it without importing. What matters is that you run the first cell before the second so that the function gets defined.

Comment: To help clarify, one colab notebook is treated as one file by python instead of many, so you do not need to import just like the answer above said.

Comment: Thanks very much it worked, i separated them in different sections so it couldn't see it